# Is it bad practice to store passwords in iCloud notes?

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash, apple, icloud

I was wondering something about a day ago when I remembered that Apple stores notes in a database (so you can recover them or view them on `icloud.com`) - What if Apple stores your notes in plaintext?

I've heard you *shouldn't* store passwords in plaintext (e.g., a MySQL DB) so is it the same with storing passwords in notes?

Comment: Use a password manager. It's made for storing secrets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to store sensitive data in your iCloud, as Apple still own your private key.

I recommend you to use [Cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/) to encrypt your cloud files.

Otherwise, there are many alternatives with zero-knowledge feature you can use, such as [CryptPad](https://cryptpad.fr/) and [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/).